# Switch image src on click

Tags: jquery, image

I have a jquery scroller i made with thumbnails and I am trying to create a mini script.

When a user clicks on the thumb nail, it updates code like this:

```
<div id="big_image">
    <img src="HERE.jpg" alt="my image"/>
</div
```

So when you click a thumbnail on the scroller it updates the SRC of the IMG tag on the page? Any ideas how I can get started?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#scroller img').click(function() {
    $('#big_image img').attr('src', whatever_full_size_image_src_is_for(this));
}
```

Comment: The difference between this answer and my answer is actually ">" character in the selector. > means select this direct children instead of all the descendants which means in my example only child imgs will be selected rather than all of descendants.

Comment: While that is true, Aaron, I don't suspect #big_picture to hold more than a single IMG as its child, based on the ID being singular.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Replace larger image with src of whatever thumbnail you clicked
$("img.myImage").click(function(){
  $("img.bigImage").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Note, unless you're crushing large images into thumbnail sizes, this won't be a very elegant solution to your problem. And in all honesty, if you *are* crushing large images into thumbnail sizes, that also isn't a very good solution.

Comment: What do you recomend if i want to say add some text to the full size image meaning image-name-full.jpg, to show the large images, then have thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function updateImage()
 { 
   $("#big_image > img").attr("src","imagePath"); 
 }
```

you can use this function in thumbnail onclick event.